# Remove header row in datatable

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I'm trying to remove the header row in a DT datatable, does anyone know if there's an option for doing this?

Minimal example:

```
#SERVER.R
output$myTable <- renderDataTable({
  datatable(dataset, rownames = FALSE, selection = 'none', options = list(dom = 't'))
})

#UI.R
dataTableOutput('myTable')
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295899/remove-header-in-data-table-after-using-transpose

Answer (score 11):

Just add `colnames = NULL` to your `datatable()`

```
datatable(mtcars, rownames = FALSE,colnames=NULL, selection = 'none', options = list(dom = 't'))
```

See `?datatable`

Answer (score 3):

Sebastian's answer from Oct 28 '15 did not work for me inside `renderDataTable(datatable(...))`. Using `colnames = NULL` inside `datatable(...)` removed all data from the table. I had to use `colnames = ""` to remove the table headers.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `colnames = NULL` no longer works and it renders an empty table. You can use `headerCallBack` option to add a css that hides the header row to achieve this.

```
headerCallback <- c(
  "function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css('display', 'none');",
  "}"
)

datatable(mtcars, 
          rownames = FALSE,
          colnames=NULL, 
          selection = 'none', 
          options = list(
            dom = 't',
            headerCallback = JS(headerCallback)
          )
)
```

Comment: Just tried with `colnames = NULL` and the column names were gone (Nov 22).